# mandril Reject Reason: unsigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailchimp, mandrill

Because of mandrill start to work with mailchimp so I have to do a new account in mailchimp after that I updates my code in the developer and production page.
But when I start to sending email it doestnt recieve and in the manderill acount I got Reject Reason: unsigned

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Do you have verified sending domain in Mandrill?

> Mail sent from unverified domains or domains without valid SPF and DKIM records will be rejected with the reject_reason, unsigned.

See picture below how you can check sending domains and their verification status

[image: Mandrill sending domain]

Hope this will help.

Comment: How to verify it ?

Comment: Link 1: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582247-About-Domain-Verification

Link 2: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582387-How-to-Set-up-Sending-Domains